# tkinter multiprocessing-root window no responding while counting down

Tags: python, tkinter, multiprocessing

Currently, I am working on my course work project and there is a simple function I want to achieve. The program is mainly on tkinter, I want the label shows up for 3 seconds, hide for 7 seconds for one period, and in the next period the text in label should change; while the label changes I am trying to disable an entry box from the first 3 seconds then normalise it.

Countdown and change of label text were alright, but the entry box does not respond at all when it is normalised.

here is my code

```
    def c_time():
    from tkinter import *
    import time

    root=Tk()
    en = Entry(root)
    en.pack(side=TOP)
    en.focus_force()
    la = Label(root, text='6666')
    la.pack(side=BOTTOM)

    li = ['a', 'b','c','d']
    for i in li:
        la.config(text=i)
        root.update()
        def la_diappear():
            root.after(3000)
            la.pack_forget()
            root.update()
        def la_appear():
            root.after(7000)
            la.pack()
        la_diappear()
        la_appear()

    root.mainloop()
c_time()
```

Both root.after and time.sleep methods were tried

and I tried multiprocessing when I reached information about GIL in python:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time
from  tkinter import *


def count_down():
    global total
    total = 5
    for i in range(total):
        time.sleep(1)
        total -= 1
        print(total)

def tkwindow():
    root=Tk()
    en = Entry(root)
    en.pack(side=TOP)
    en.focus_force()
    la = Label(root, text='6666')
    la.pack(side=BOTTOM)
    li = ['a', 'b','c','d']

    for i in li:
        la.config(text=i)
        root.update()
        count_down()
        if total == 3:
            la.pack_forget()
            root.update()
        if total == 5:
            la.pack()

    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = Process(target=count_down)
    b = Process(target=tkwindow)
    b.start()
```

the code above should be work straight away.

plz reply if any thought related

Thank you very much.

Comment: _"Both root.after and time.sleep methods were tried"_ `root.after` with a single argument is identical to `time.sleep` -- it pauses the entire application, and should almost never be done in the same thread and process as the rest of the GUI.

Comment: If passing function in root.after(), should I put `la.pack_forget()` ` root.update()` in a function, then do `root.after(3000, forget_func)`? @BryanOakley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the `for` loop in a function, and thread that function. Then you can also use `time.sleep` without blocking the main thread.

```
from tkinter import *
from threading import Thread
import time

root=Tk()
en = Entry(root)
en.pack(side=TOP)
en.focus_force()
la = Label(root, text='6666')
la.pack(side=BOTTOM)

def la_diappear():
    la.pack_forget()

def la_appear():
    la.pack()

def actions():
    li = ['a', 'b','c','d']
    for i in li:
        la.config(text=i)
        time.sleep(3)
        la_diappear()
        time.sleep(7)
        la_appear()

t = Thread(target=actions)
t.start()

root.mainloop()
```